# How to Sum and Group Data Frame Elements?

Tags: python, pandas

```
+-----+-------+--------+
|     | Buyer |  Sex   |
+-----+-------+--------+
| 0   | 1     | Male   |
| 1   | 1     | Female |
| 2   | 0     | Male   |
| 3   | 1     | Female |
| ... | ...   | ...    |
+-----+-------+--------+
```

I'd like to sum and group the data frame above, into the data frame (table) below. Does pandas have any built-in-functions that can accomplish this or do I have to manually iterate, sum, and group?

```
+---+---------+------+
|   | Female  | Male |
+---+---------+------+
| 0 |      81 |  392 |
| 1 |     539 |  233 |
+---+---------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pivot_table`, with `'count'` as your aggfunc. 
Also, considering there might be some combinations never found, use `fillna`  to fill the empty cells with 0:

```
In [28]:
df['V'] = 1
print df
   Buyer     Sex  V
0      1    Male  1
1      1  Female  1
2      0    Male  1
3      1  Female  1
In [29]:
print df.pivot_table(index='Buyer', columns='Sex', values='V', aggfunc='count').fillna(0)
Sex    Female  Male
Buyer              
0           0     1
1           2     1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
frame.groupby('Sex').aggregate(some_function)
```

should work.
or even in your case :

```
frame.groupby('Sex').sum()
```